# normalize CSS developer tools chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have a page where there is a CSS file there is minified.

In google chrome developer there is under "Sources" an option where you can normalize CSS. Can anybody remember where that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fount out after 1 hour... Click on the curly brackets, just above the console window.